# How do I find which of two tables has the row with a given value in a known column

Tags: php, mysql, union

If I have two tables in a MySQL database that both have a column called `order_number`, given an `order_number` value but not knowing which table it comes from how would I go about setting up a query that would return the name of the table it was found in?

I am particularly interested in the name of the table so I can set up subsequent updates to that table.

Also, I am using PHP for the handling of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select "tableA" as tableName,order_number from tableA where order_number=5
UNION
select "tableB" as tableName,order_number from tableB where order_number=5;
```

Comment: is `tableName` a keyword in MySQL?

Comment: @Zak - No, it is just an arbitrary name.  It could just has easily been "tableA" as this_is_the_table_Zak_wants... I was just using it as a variable to store a custom string in.

Comment: Oh right, I had completely missed variable assignment in MySQL. Cheers this does exactly what I am after :)

Comment: No worries, I actually did too at first :)  Good luck.